# excel xml window width property

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, excel

This answer is strangely vacant from the internet, or my google-fu is getting rusty.

I'm making an excel file from C# via xml... When it loads up the worksheet width is pitifully small. Using `<ss:WindowWidth>13395</ss:WindowWidth>`
as prescribed by the internet does... nothing. (edit: tried this in excelworkbook and worksheetoptions, if that gives any idea to the problem) Tried with and without the ss: additions. Also, I cannot seem to find exactly why everyone uses values with this in and around the tens of thousands.

I'm thoroughly confused. If someone links a LMGTFY that answers this I'll eat my hat, because I damn well don't see it.

Silly excel. No one likes you.

Just for you L.
Figured *windowWidth* would give the jist of it.

[image]

Comment: "the worksheet width is pitifully small" - meaning the width of the window on the screen? or the number of columns in the worksheet? or ...? Maybe a screenshot would help...

Comment: What version(s) of office you are targeting?

Comment: @Remm, are you going to award the Bounty?

Comment: oh, apparently you're supposed to double click the bounty button. I only clicked it once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen some people add an `ExcelWorkbook` element to the 'Workbook' element. The `ExcelWorkbook` element has `WindowWidth` and `WindowHeight` elements.

Here is an example that lists (all?) of the child elements for the `ExcelWorkbook` element.

```
<Workbook>
   <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <WindowHeight>6795</WindowHeight>
      <WindowWidth>8460</WindowWidth>
      <WindowTopX>120</WindowTopX>
      <WindowTopY>15</WindowTopY>
      <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
      <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
   </ExcelWorkbook>
   ...
</Workbook>
```

**EDIT**

The `WindowWidth` element is an unsigned int that is specified in twips. Twips is defined as a twentieth of a point.

Twips Link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip

Comment: I already have this...
A part of the question, though, pertains to the windowheight/width values. What units are they in? '6795' as a programmer doesn't mean jack.

Comment: I interpreted "Using <ss:WindowWidth>13395</ss:WindowWidth> as prescribed by the internet does... nothing" that to mean, it does not control the width, help. The what units are these seemed secondary to the fact that the width was not being controlled.

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize the workbook programmatically via the COM interface. In VBA you would do something like this:

```
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Maybe that helps.

Comment: I am sending an XML file to the client (C# asp.net). It needs to be done in the xml that I'm sending, which windowWidth should do... but doesn't.